# ngmodelgroup. Value changes. Subscribe doesn’t work

Tags: angular6

I want to subscribe to the ngmodelgroup field changes

@viewchild(‘mdlgrp’) modelgroup: Ngmodelgroup

ngOninit(){

this.mdlgrp.valuesChanges.subscribe()

// gives error
}

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
    (this.modelgroup.formDirective as NgForm)
        .statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
        
    });
```